# How to use CSRF protection on forms?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, csrf

I would like to just use Spring's Cross Site Request Forgery protection in Spring without any login authentication system. I tried but I don't know why it does not work without an authentication manager. I am trying to implement it in a website just to protect form submissions from being sent from other places.

Comment: Did you tried spring-security features??

Comment: Spring Security CSRF docs are here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/csrf.html